# How to successfully destroy a MediaElementPlayer and create a new one

Tags: mediaelement.js

Here's the scenario:

I have a page that contains a `video` element which is set up with a video. The source of this video may be HTML5 video with multiple sources (and Flash fallback) or a YouTube video.
Beneath this is a number of images which serve as video thumbnails, clicking on one should load the appropriate video, by destroying the existing MediaElementPlayer and creating a new one on the same `video` element.

This creates the initial player on page load:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({ alwaysShowControls: true });
```

And this is intended to change the player when one of the images is clicked:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
   alwaysShowControls: true,
   success: function(media, dom, player) {
      console.log('success!');
   },
   error: function() {
      console.log('error!');
   }
});
```

But it doesn't work. The `success` function is never entered (neither is `error`) and nothing appears to happen.

I guess the library still thinks that the original player exists or something, and have tried a number of things to try and tell it that this isn't the case, for example:

```
mejs.meIndex = 0
mejs.players = []
```

To no effect, and setting:

```
window.mejs = null;
window.MediaElementPlayer = null;
window.MediaElement = null;
```

Just breaks things :)

Can anyone out there help? I'm sure I'm missing something simple here so I'd be very grateful if someone could point out what! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here for anyone else who might have the same issue and stumble across this entry.

It turns out that what I want to do is not supported my MediaElementJS at the time of writing this.

My solution was to create two players and use one for HTML5/Flash videos and the other for YouTube videos, showing and hiding the appropriate one as required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `remove()` method of medialementjs, set the type and src attribute of your `video` element and then reinitialize mediaelementjs if the video type has changed.

Could look something like this:

```
function setSource(url, type) {
    var vid = $('#video').first();
    if (vid.attr('type') != type) {
        vid.get(0).player.remove();
        vid.attr('type', type).attr('src', url);
        vid.mediaelementplayer({
            success: function(media, dom, player) {
                player.play();
            }
        })

    }
}
```

If you don't only have mp4 and youtube you can add additional logic to only reinitialize when needed. Works perfect for me.

Comment: instead of 'remove()' your code sample calls 'destroy()' (which is not supported by mediaelement.js)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up storing the original video tag html before initialising the video using mediaelementplayer().  When I want to switch the video I jQuery("parent").empty() the parent element of the video destroying the elements mediaelementjs created, then restore the original video html and reinitialise using:

```
$("#video").mediaelementplayer({
    pauseOtherPlayers: false
});
```

I bit hacky but does the job.  I am interested to know if you have found a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to switch different types of video src, you need to destroy the player and create a new one.

To destroy the player:

```js
try(){
    player.pause();
    player.remove(ture);
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to change the current video played be MediaElementJS is not to destroy it and recreate it again, but to use the built-in video "src" attribute to change the source.

Using the MediaElementJS API to access this "src" attribute is the better way to manage cross-browser cross-source issues (for YouTube video for instance, or Flash fallback). Here is the way I've done it:

```
player.pause();
player.setSrc(myNewSourceURL);
player.load();
```

I also have turned this code into a MediaElementJS plugin, will a lot of nice things around like playlist management, next and prev buttons, and a playlist panel. You can find [the pullRequest on github](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/pull/632).

Here is a code example to build a playlist:

```
new MediaElementPlayer('#myvideo', {
    features : ['prev','playpause','next', 'progress'],
    success : function(mediaElement, domObject){
        domObject.player.loadPlaylist([
            {src: "http://domain.com/video/video1.mp4"},
            {src: "http://domain.com/video/video2.mp4"},
            {src: "http://domain.com/video/video3.mp4"},
        ]);
    }
});
```

Then, when a thumbnail is clicked :

```
var index = 2; // calculate the item index in the playlist
player.setItem(index);
```

Comment: That doesn't work when you want to switched between a HTML5 video source and a YouTube video. The creator of the library confirmed that such a switch is not supported.